# Removing cursor from Matlab edit uicontrol after user has updated it?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, uicontrol

Hi to all Matlab wizards --

I apologize if this is a trivial question. How does one remove the blinking cursor from an edit uicontrol box after the user had pressed "enter" (and the callback got invoked)? I thought pressing "enter" would remove the cursor by default, since the user is "done" with the input, but no. I thought "selected" would be the property, but no, that's different.

I could not find this by googling (the latter works most of the time).

Cheers!

Comment: Move the focus somewhere else, maybe the next uicontrol.

Comment: Thank you, Stark. It sems that this would merely move the problem to another uicontrol. I do not want the focus on any uicontrol, bur rather the figure in "focus" (which is not the same as being at the top) -- i.e. in a state when the fig accepts ButtonDnFcn callbacks again, w/o having to click anywhere at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dummy` uicontrol to replicate the behaviour that (I think) you are after, see this example code which gives you the behaviour you want

```
% create a figure
f = figure;
% set keypress and button down callbacks
f.KeyPressFcn = @(a,b)disp('press on figure' );
f.ButtonDownFcn = @(a,b)disp('button on figure' );
% create a dummy uicontrol as a text object with no text
t = uicontrol ( f, 'style' , 'text' );
% create a edit control
% set the callback to move the foccus to the dummy uicontrol
e = uicontrol ( f, 'style', 'edit', 'Callback', @(a,b)uicontrol(t) );
% set the key press and the button down callbacks of the dummy figure
% to run the callbacks of the figure
t.KeyPressFcn= @(obj,evt)feval(f.KeyPressFcn);
t.ButtonDownFcn= @(obj,evt)feval(f.ButtonDownFcn);
```

Now when you enter text into the edit box and press enter the focus moves to the new uicontrol where the callbacks are linked to the figure callbacks

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution to my problem (inspired by https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/65223-deselect-uimenus-after-click-in-gui)

```
%callback function for the control
function update_control (hdl,event)
            set(hdl, 'Enable', 'off');
            drawnow;
            set(hdl, 'Enable', 'on');
set(gcf,'CurrentObject',default_object);
```

This removes the blinking cursor and returns the GUI interactivity to the previous object that the user was interacting with.